# Implement a c# windows forms Autocomplete textbox with multiple suggested columns

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, multiple-columns

I am attempting to implement a Windows Forms control in C# that resembles a textbox.  When the user types 3 or more characters, a search will be performed against a datasource.  There will be multiple fields returned (see the class structure below as one possible definition).

```
public class MyStructure
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 {get; set; }
}
```

My requirements are to display an autocomplete list containing multiple columns (Note: this can be a string that contains padded fields from the list that are concatenated together).  When the user either types all characters, hits the down arrow to select an item, or hits the enter key the value in the textbox will take the ValueMember of the list (where the DisplayMember of the list would be the whole data source).  Every keystroke that the user enters that is not an up or down arrow or the enter key will perform another search and refresh the list.

I have seen how to implement a textbox with a single column in an auto-suggest, but cannot find a relatively "simple" example of how to do this for multiple columns.  Should the control be a textbox or a combobox that is somehow styled to resemble a textbox (if this is possible) or a user control?

Should the event to monitor keystrokes be the TextEntered or the KeyPress event?  Can I reset the AutoCompleteStringCollection without having the contents entered affected (I keep losing my input or my place in the input in any attempts)?

Can anyone provide examples of how to do this in framework 4.0 or above or point me to an example?

**EDIT 1:**
After much searching, I have found that essentially I need to implement a ContextMenuStrip on the TextBox (anything else and other controls below the user control will be overlapped).  My problem is that I cannot determine how to handle the Key press events such as Tab and Enter.  In addition, I need to handle if the user continues typing (in this event, I want to switch focus back to the textbox and add the key). Below is my code:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip menuStrip;
        string szMenuItem = string.Empty;

        // This would actually be a call to a web service
        List<MStarDeal> deals = DealInfo.Where(i => i.Value1.StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()) || i.Value2.StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()) || i.Value3.StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()))
            .Select(i => i).ToList();

        if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 3 && !bSelected)
        {
            menuStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();

            foreach (MStarDeal item in deals)
            {
                szMenuItem = item.Value1.PadRight(15) + item.Value2.PadRight(20) + item.Value3.PadRight(80);

                ToolStripItem tsItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                tsItem.Text = szMenuItem;
                tsItem.Name = item.Value1;
                tsItem.MouseUp += tsItem_MouseUp;
                menuStrip.Items.Add(tsItem);
            }

            textBox1.ContextMenuStrip = menuStrip;
            textBox1.ContextMenuStrip.Show(textBox1, new Point(0, 20));
        }
        else if (bSelected)
        {
            bSelected = false;
        }
    }

    void tsItem_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bSelected = true;
        textBox1.Text = ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Name;
    }
```

Thanks,

Lee

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question.  How about using the TextChanged() event instead of KeyPress?  As far as the columns, a flowLayoutPanel will render columns if you set it up to flow in the right direction and make its size appropriate to the width of the two columns combined.

Comment: In this example, how do I link the flowlayoutpanel to the textbox so that entering info into the textbox links to the flowlayoutpanel?  Should I not implement the autocompletestringcollection and related properties in this case (i.e. everything is done off of the TextChanged event)?  How do I prevent this position in the text of the textbox from being erased?

Comment: That one, I don't know.  It might be easier to not use the autoCompleteSource, etc. properties.   Why not, within TextChanged event, perform your search textBox1.Text on the data source?  Then, add whatever matches you find as label controls to the flowlayoutPanel?  It will show in columns, just like you want.

Comment: I will try that - though I think I need the KeyPress event instead.  That way, every time a key is pressed - the key will be evaluated. If the key is an arrow key then focus would switch to the flowlayoutpanel to move up or down.  An event would be added to set the textbox text and switch focus back.  I will try it tomorrow and post the answer.